# Given age is normally distributed with mean = 7.2, s = 1.9. What is the probability that out of 5 people, 2 would be older than 10?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I was considering finding p(x>10) and converting into z values (and a standard normal distribution), and then taking this as the "success" rate and inputting it into a binomial distribution with n = 5, choosing 2, and success rate = p (x>10).

What do you think? Would that work or is this not correct?

Comment: sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Is there any other way or is this the correct answer?

Comment: Certainly this is the method I'd use.  Nothing wrong with it (well, subject to the usual assumptions that the choices of individuals are independent).  If your sample was large, you'd want to approximate the process with a normal, but with such a small sample it's far better to do it exactly, as you have proposed.

Comment: Great thank you very much!

Comment: Suppose a club only wants to allow 15% of this population to enter. How can I know what age is the cut-off point?

Comment: Just use the cumulative distribution function. You want $x$ so that $P(Age<x)=.15$.  I get $5.23$, but I did it hastily so you ought to check.

Comment: I did that and got 9.166 :(

Comment: Well, maybe you are solving $P(Age>x)=.15$ .  It's a symmetric distribution about the mean so we see that $9.166-7.2\approx 7.2-5.23$.